# Neural Network written in Kotlin working for simple math problems but not for MNIST classification

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, accuracy, mnist

I'm building a neural network in **Kotlin** while reading the book *"Neural Networks and Deep Learning"* from Michael Nielsen.

At the moment the network uses: *sigmoid neurons, backpropagation, stochastic gradient descent, $1 \over \sqrt {n_{in}}$ standard deviation for weight initialization, L2 regularization, and cross-entropy*. I also created a plotter to monitor the learning process.

Here is how the network behaves with a simple problem, **finding the bigger of two numbers**:

[image: plot1]

Pretty good, we have a peak of **99.99%**.
I can't understand why the cost is increasing instead of decreasing, but still the accuracy is good.
Things get way worse with **MNIST classification**; the net is basically giving random answers:

[image: plot2]

I wonder what can change the behaviour of the network this much.
I checked the MNIST data, and it seems all right.
What problem can cause this kind of learning absence? The algorithm is broken? The hyper-parameters are wrong?
All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem on my own. Turns out that the problem was indeed in the **hyper-parameters**, as I suspected.

I was using the same values as *Michael Nielsen* so it seemed strange to me that they could be wrong - by a mathematical point of view, my network is exactly the same as his one! - anyway, lowering the $\eta$ and raising the $\lambda$ (in practice, lowering the weights/biases changes on a single batch) lets the network to better understand which direction it should take to minimize the cost function.
I can now get accuracies above **85%**, and I'm sure that with a bit of fine-tuning I can reach at least **95%**.

I also solved the *cost plot problem*:

> I can't understand why the cost is increasing instead of decreasing [...]

The problem was that instead of doing something like

$C= -{1 \over n} ∑_{xj} [y_j ln(a^L_j) + (1−y_j) ln(1−a^L_j)] + {λ \over 2n} ∑_w w^2$

I was doing

$C= -{1 \over n} ∑_{xj} [y_j ln(a^L_j) + (1−y_j) ln(1−a^L_j) + {λ \over 2n} ∑_w w^2]$

which doesn't make sense, since the last term equals to

$∑_{xj} {λ \over 2n} ∑_w w^2 = n {λ \over 2n} ∑_w w^2 = {λ \over 2} ∑_w w^2$

and so we get a wrong regularization factor for the weights.